# Creating custom mail filter for office 365

Tags: email, smtp, office365

I need to write a custom email filter (something like a spam filter) that will intercept to every mail that will be received in the organization's SMTP server
and will check the mail's content with a program that i will write (Saw that in EOP there is a built-in spam filter - but i want to write custom code...)

How it can be implemented with office 365 ? i saw that there are connectors that you can define - that will router traffic to other SMTP server (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj723138(v=exchg.150).aspx)
Can I route all the inbound mail of 365 to the connector before the users can access the emails? 
(I don't want to set the filter between the internet to the 365 (and change the MX record) , but i would prefer to put it inside the 365 with the routings)

Is there other approach to it? some kind of API to ?

Thanks!